# Element-UI datepicker start of the week?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I need date picker to show start of the week as Monday, instead of Sunday, docs don't say anything about it and how to change it or I completely missed it.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a **firstDayOfWeek** property of Picker Options. It accept a number indicate first day of week count from Monday. Default value is 7, set it to 1 would work for you.